# Algolia not importing my records laravel scout

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am using laravel scout to implement my text search. I followed all the configuration instructions and imported the records. When I do that i get this success message `Imported [App\Thread] models up to ID: 8` but in algolia I can't see my records for the given index, it keeps saying I have 0 records. I am currently using my admin APIkey.

How do I fix that?

Comment: did you do php artisan scout:import

Comment: Yes and right after that i get the success message specified above

Comment: please try my answer and hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have this problem. it is weird but after i did:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dumpautoload
```

I can do `php artisan scout:import` without any problem. But when i switched the driver, it didn't work again, and i had to do the 4 steps above again to fix it.

Comment: have you installed the scout package also?

Comment: clear the index on algolia and then try again importing

Comment: For others using Algolia wherein an index is created on import but zero records are imported wherein the above fix doesn't work, check your queue connection settings and possibly disable the queue for testing to see if that's the issue. In my case, incomplete queue config was causing records not to get imported without any warnings, e.g. the import was pushing to the queue and getting stuck there w/o errors.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem. I was using `sqs` for queue driver and i had to run queue worker to function the importing to algolia.

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem with in my local , so i runned meilisearch without master key, and it fixed